# What format are the files in /usr/share/doc/ in?

Tags: linux, redhat, documentation

I found a nice wealth of information on some commands that I use in `/usr/share/doc`. Some are in a weird format though with tags such as:

- `\verbatim` and `\endverbatim`
- `\section` and `\endsection`

Any idea what format this is? E.g. of one of the files: `/usr/share/doc/rpm-*/spec`

Comment: Maybe troff?  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Troff

Comment: Almost all of the documents on my SL6.1 system are plain text. There are a few which seem to be in some sort of Markup language (lAtEx?). There are even a few in HTML, or PDFs!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a LaTeX file. The file(1) command is useful for determining a file's type, e.g.:

```
$ file /usr/share/doc/rpm-4.8.1/*                                                                                                        
/usr/share/doc/rpm-4.8.1/builddependencies: ASCII English text                                                                           
/usr/share/doc/rpm-4.8.1/buildroot:         LaTeX document text                                                                          
/usr/share/doc/rpm-4.8.1/ChangeLog.bz2:     bzip2 compressed data, block size = 900k                                                     
/usr/share/doc/rpm-4.8.1/conditionalbuilds: ASCII English text                                                                           
/usr/share/doc/rpm-4.8.1/COPYING:           ASCII English text                                                                           
[...]
/usr/share/doc/rpm-4.8.1/spec:              LaTeX document text                                                   
/usr/share/doc/rpm-4.8.1/triggers:          LaTeX document text                                                                          
/usr/share/doc/rpm-4.8.1/tsort:             LaTeX document text
```

Comment: Thanks! Any idea how to best view them?

Comment: Just run  `pdflatex FILENAME.tex` which will produce `FILENAME.pdf`. Sometimes you are lucky and the file is shebang'ed in which case you just execute the file. If you get stuck ask on [TeX.StackExchange](http://tex.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like **[LaTeX](http://www.latex-project.org/)** format